# Testing Activities in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm wanting to unit test some interactions on activity lifecycle (I'm working on a data binding library, that can't have unit tests without it).

Android has some good [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) on the subject. However, I've not found anyone that has attempted to do this with Xamarin. Many of the [classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/package-summary.html) in `android.test` are missing in Xamarin.

So far I've attempted something like the following in the Xamarin test project that uses NUnit:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyActivityTests
    {
        private TestActivity _activity;
        private TestViewModel _viewModel;
        private Instrumentation _instrumentation;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _viewModel = new TestViewModel();
            _activity = new TestActivity();

            _instrumentation = new InstrumentationTestRunner();
            _instrumentation.Start();
            _instrumentation.CallActivityOnCreate(_activity, Bundle.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Later on I'd have tests that use the activity.

I also have to set the following in my manifest:

```
<application android:label="My Tests">
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
```

The problem is, in my unit test above a `Java.Lang.NullPointerException` is thrown in my activity's `base.OnCreate()` method. I'm sure I'm missing something, because I'm in uncharted waters here.

Here is the stack trace:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.2-branch/35376881/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.2-branch/35376881/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-18/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2193
[MonoDroid] at XamBind.Droid.Tests.TestActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00003] in /Users/jonathanpeppers/Desktop/MonoTouch/XamBind/XamBind.Droid.Tests/Activities/TestActivity.cs:19
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.2-branch/35376881/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-18/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2178
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.640629b6-d042-45f3-840b-28e31832a912 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0001f>
[MonoDroid] 
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.NullPointerException
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:884)
[MonoDroid]     at xambind.droid.tests.TestActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at xambind.droid.tests.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:28)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
[MonoDroid]     at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone attempted this before?

Comment: Can you post the activity's `onCreate` method and the line on which the NPE is occurring? Or, does the NPE happen on the `base.OnCreate` call?

Comment: I added the full stack trace above.

Comment: Alright, so it's happening at `android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:884)`. Which Android SDK version are you using? We could look at the `android.app.Activity` class for that SDK version to see what's throwing the NPE.

Comment: This is in my manifest `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`, right now pretty arbitrary, since I just picked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this isn't supported yet with Xamarin.Android: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6043

Because this stuff depends on JUnit, they can't bind the classes to C#. Hopefully they get it working and its coming.

What I did for my situation was to rewrite my library so you don't have to subclass `Activity`, then I could write my tests no problem.

Comment: The link is dead. Do you have a sample somewhere?