# Xamarin android mocking shared preferences

Tags: android, mocking, nunit, xamarin

I have an android unit test project which uses NUnit to test my Xamarin Android project and need to mock a shared preferences object. I have attempted to use the following to mock an ISharedPreferences:

```
new MockContext().GetSharedPreferences("",Android.Content.FileCreationMode.Append);
```

However this results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.test.mock.MockContext"
```

I have included the following using statement in my project **using Android.Test.Mock**.

I do not know why it cannot find the class when the code compiles and builds successfully in Xamarin?

Comment: What mocking library are  you using for this?

Comment: This is the standard mocking library with xamarin android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that most of these class are not yet supported by Xamarin yet. Some other users have alluded to this in previous posts as well:
[Testing Activities in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598130/testing-activities-in-xamarin-android)

Unfortunately there is no solution to mocking as of yet with Xamarin. See my other question at 
[Mocking framework for use with xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538727/mocking-framework-for-use-with-xamarin-android). For now we will just have to live with using manual mocking.